# Swift google sign in

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i'm trying to add the Google signIn in my app (with firebase) and i can get a successfully access but i don't know how i can change the viewController after this

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import GoogleSignIn

class FirstClass: UIViewController , FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var FirstClass: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var signButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var customSegmented: CustomSegmentedControl!


    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()


/*  let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString) */






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       /* GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()  */

        setupGoogleButtons()

        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 67, y: 536, width: 118, height: 41 )
        loginButton.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }






    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome1", sender: self)
        }

    }



    fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons() {

        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 189, y: 536, width: 118, height: 41)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
}





    func handleCustomGoogleSign() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}











    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", error)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }

            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }
```

here is the relevant part of the viewController's code where the google signIn button is. Where i've to add the "perform segue" to change the view after a successfully log in ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this to perform a segue in Appdelegate

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            for controller in navigationController.viewControllers {
                if let LoginViewController = controller as? LogInViewContoller {
                    LoginViewController.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInToHome", sender: nil)
                    break
                }
```

You can put this piece of code after you sign in in Appdelegate. This way, once you are logged in, you are able to go directly to the next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question :

Update your **auth** part of the code in *sign function* with the below code :

```
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }

        print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)

        self.Segue()
    })
```

And make **Segue** function

```
 func Segue(){
    //add your code here to perform the seague
  }
```

This is my code for the authentication:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email!, password: password!, completion: { (user, error) in
        guard let _ = user else {
            if let error = error {
                if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {
                    switch errCode {
                    case .invalidEmail:
                        print("User account not found. Try registering")
                    case .wrongPassword:
                        print("Incorrect username/password combination")
                    default:
                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
                return
            }
            assertionFailure("user and error are nil")
            return
        }
        self.Segue()
    })
```

and the segue function :

```
    func segue(){
    let control = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifer")
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([control], animated: true)
}
```

Comment: it not working, come back on the original viewController after the log in

Comment: Try to set the view controller it will not come back :

let control = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifer") navigationController?.setViewControllers([control], animated: true)

Comment: Apply breakpoint on the segue function and see if it goes inside the code. this code works for my app

Comment: did but still the same result the func not goes inside the code

Comment: @bero also please insure that your view controller are embedded in navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

If your home page is a view controller that is different than your login view controller, then you can do the following line of code in your `sign` function after you successfully log a user in:

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

otherwise you can do this:

```
  let newController = OtherViewController()

    // switch to OtherControllerView
    present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Where `OtherViewController` is the name of the view controller you would like to switch to after successfully logging in a user

Your authentication completion block could thus look like this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
        let newController = OtherViewController()

        // switch to OtherControllerView
        present(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Comment: it not working, after the log in come back in the original viewController

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect after successfully login with Google. Here i am calling doLogin Method for redirection

```
    //MARK: - Sign In With Google -
        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
            if (error == nil){
                var picUrl: URL!
                if user.profile.hasImage{
                    picUrl = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100)
                }
                let gPlusDic = ["userId" : user.userID, "authToken" : user.authentication.idToken, "fullName" : user.profile.name, "email" : user.profile.email, "pic" : picUrl] as [String : Any]
                print(gPlusDic)
                self.doLogin(intTagGPlus, userDict: gPlusDic as [String : AnyObject]) //Here you can redirect with your particular viewController
            }
            else{ showMessage("", message: "\(error)" , VC: self)
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        private func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
```

> Also add these two methods in Appdelegate for handeling Google and
>   fb URL scheme

```
//MARK: - Handle URL for FB and Google Sign -
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        //handle the URL that your application receives at the end of the authentication process -
        var flag: Bool = false
        // handle Facebook url scheme
        if let wasHandled:Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) {
            flag = wasHandled
        }
        // handle Google url scheme
        if let googlePlusFlag: Bool = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation) {
            flag = googlePlusFlag
        }
        return flag
    }
```

Comment: What is SVProgressHUD?

Comment: it's third party progressCotroll for showing Progress

Comment: how i can declare it?

Comment: its thirdparty library so you have to install through Pod or manually add from here https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

Comment: SVProgressHUD.dismiss()  i did it for my purpose untill the signin prossess is not completing. @bero

Comment: may be you are not handeling Google and fb URL scheme in your app, see my updated code @bero

Answer (score 0):

````
### Google SignIn

**#### Step 0.**
Create Project,
https://console.developers.google.com/

Enable Google SignIn and  copy API Secret Key and URL Scheme. 

**#### Step 1.**
Go to 'Project > Info > URL Type' 

Click on + Button and add your scheme which you'll get from Google Developer Console.

"swift 

 com.googleusercontent.apps.347588593514-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

"

**#### Step2.**
Add these

```swift

 import GoogleSignIn

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  GoogleSignInHelper.shared.initialize()

  return true
}

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
 return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
  sourceApplication:   options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
  annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
````

````
#### Step3.

```swift

import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonSignin: GIDSignInButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func signInButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

GoogleSignInHelper.shared.requestForSignIn { (user, error) in

        print(user)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
````

**GoogleSignInHelper.swift**

```
import Foundation
import GoogleSignIn

struct GoogleUser {
var userID: String!
var name: String!
var email: String!
var hasImage: Bool!
var imagePath: URL?
}

class GoogleSignInHelper: NSObject, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

typealias GoogleSignInHanlder = (_ user:GoogleUser?, _ error: Error?)->()

private var handler: GoogleSignInHanlder?
private let instance = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
public static let shared = GoogleSignInHelper()

private func prepareGoogleUser(_ user: GIDGoogleUser) -> GoogleUser {
    
    var localUser = GoogleUser()
    localUser.userID = user.userID
    localUser.email = user.profile.email
    localUser.name = user.profile.givenName
    localUser.hasImage = user.profile.hasImage
    localUser.imagePath = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 250)
    
    return localUser
}

private func successfullLogged(user: GoogleUser) {
    if let completionHandler = handler {
        completionHandler(user, nil)
    }
}

private func failedHandler(error: Error) {
    if let completionHandler = handler {
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}

public func initialize() {
    
    // Initialize sign-in
    instance?.clientID = GoogleConfig.oAuthKey //CLIENT_KEY
    instance?.delegate = GoogleSignInHelper.shared
    instance?.uiDelegate = GoogleSignInHelper.shared
}

public func requestForSignIn(onCompletion:@escaping GoogleSignInHanlder) {
    
    handler = onCompletion
    instance?.signIn()
}

public func requestForSignOut() {
    instance?.signOut()
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    
}

func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
 
    //onGoogleSignInAction
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    
    if let error = error {
        // onFailure
        failedHandler(error: error)
    } else {
        
        // onSuccessfull Authentication
        successfullLogged(user: prepareGoogleUser(user))
    }
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    
    // onFailure
    failedHandler(error: error)
}
}
```